# Are privatekeys Case-sensitive?

Tags: private-key

I want to print privatekey into block of steel, but I have only uppercase letters, so I wonder if privatekey is case sensitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A private key is a 256-bit number. You can represent it using only digits (so there is no need for lowercase letters). However, if you want to use the [Wallet import format](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format) to represent the key, then you will need both upper and lower case letters (keys are encoded in [Base58](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding)).